# Entity Framework Core: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint Cannot insert duplicate key in object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am getting the following error when inserting records into a child table, Why is Entity Framework Core trying to insert a record into the parent table(IdentityUser table) when I am asking it to insert a record into a child table(Keywords table)?

**StackTrace:**

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_IdentityUser'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.IdentityUser'. The duplicate key value is (39b72c3a-b5bf-43e4-84f9-5cddbe79f6e3).
The statement has been terminated.
```

**Model:**

```
public class Keyword
{
    public Keyword() { }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int KeywordId { get; set; }
    public IdentityUser User { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

**Code to save records to Keywords table:**

```
var keywords = new List<Keyword>();
var identityUser = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User);
foreach (var keywordString in keywordsThatNeedToBeSaved)
{
    keywords.Add(new Keyword
    {
        User = identityUser,
        Value = keywordString
    });
}
ScrubberDbContext.Keywords.AddRange(keywords);
await ScrubberDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `identityUser` exist in database and you add it in keywords entity when you want to save keywords, Entityframework again save `identityUser` and that is exist then it has a error, you should add userId in your Keyword Entity and then add userid when you want save keywords entity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change keyword class to:

```
public class Keyword
{
    public Keyword() { }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int KeywordId { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public IdentityUser User { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

and change save record to:

```
var keywords = new List<Keyword>();
var identityUser = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User);
foreach (var keywordString in keywordsThatNeedToBeSaved)
{
    keywords.Add(new Keyword
    {
        UserId = identityUser.Id,
        Value = keywordString
    });
}
ScrubberDbContext.Keywords.AddRange(keywords);
await ScrubberDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```